# What is the correct GA4 audience scope setting based on session and event criteria?

Tags: google-analytics-4

I have difficulty choosing scope when creating an audience group.

For example, given that:

- membership duration is 30 days as default
- condition is to include users when dimension "Page path & query string" contains a certain string (= any event whose event parameter "page_url" contains a certain string)
- John had 2 sessions A and B that met the criteria on 5/6, 1 session C that met the criteria on 5/7, and 1 session D that **didn't** meet the criteria on 5/8.

According to the condition scope, there are 4 situations:

1. Across all sessions (dynamic evaluation)

- when John had sessions A and B on 5/6, he is included in the group.
- when John had session C on 5/7, he is kept in the group as all his sessions so far (A,B,C) met the criteria.
- when John had session D on 5/8, he is **immediately excluded** from the group as one of his sessions (D from A,B,C,D) didn't meet the criteria.

2. Across all sessions + "At any point" is checked (static evaluation)

- when John had sessions A and B on 5/6, he is included in the group.
- when John had session C on 5/7, he is kept in the group as all his sessions so far (A,B,C) met the criteria.
- when John had session D on 5/8, he is **kept** in the group as he once met the criteria even though he doesn't anymore.
- if John doesn't have any session that meet the criteria by 6/7 (= the last time membership duration is updated on 5/7 and + 30 days), he will be excluded from the group.

3. Within the same session

- when John had session A and B on 5/6, he is included in the group.
- when John had session C on 5/7, he is kept in the group and the membership duration is reset.
- when John had session D on 5/8, he is **kept** in the group as the membership duration doesn't expire.
- if John doesn't have any session that meet the criteria by 6/7 (the last time membership duration is updated on 5/7 and +30 days), he will be excluded from the group.

4. Within the same event

- when John had such event in session A and B on 5/6, he is included in the group.
- when John had such event in session C on 5/7, he is kept in the group and the membership duration is reset.
- when John had no such event in session D on 5/8, he is **kept** in the group as the membership duration doesn't expire.
- if John doesn't have any event that meet the criteria by 6/7 (the last time membership duration is updated on 5/7 and +30 days), he will be excluded from the group.

I assume the audience size would be like this: 1 < 2 = 3 = 4.

But the estimated audience size shown on the GA4 interface is actually: 1 < 3 < 4 = 2.

Can anyone tell me why using this example?

Any thoughts would be helpful. Thanks!!